# I am unable to find the error in my php file

Tags: php, syntax

Hello friends I don't have much skills in php. Please help me with this code. It is displaying syntax error unexpected end of file. I have tested but failed. When I delete this code form the file the page is displaying correctly but again when I paste this code it is displaying the same error.

The file has this code only so there could be a bracket, fullstop or other problem please correct it give the fixed code in your answers. Love you all you guys are really helping the needy people.

```
<?php
include("include/header.php");
if (!isset($_SESSION["userlogin"])) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit();
}
$edit = dbFetchArray(dbQuery("select * from `user_registration` where `email`='" . $_SESSION["userlogin"] . "'"), MYSQL_BOTH);
$Id = base64_decode($_REQUEST['Id']);
$up = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from `jobs` where `id`='" . $Id . "'"));
$status = stripslashes($up["highlighted"]);
$name = stripslashes($up["title"]);
$explode = explode(" ", $name);
$tit = isset($explode[0]) ? $explode[0] : '';
$col = isset($explode[1]) ? $explode[1] : '';
$cat = isset($explode[2]) ? $explode[2] : '';

$user = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from `user_registration` where `email`='" . $_SESSION["userlogin"] . "'"));
$fullname = stripslashes($user['fullname']);
$customer_id = $user['id'];
$current_balence = $user['current_balance'];

if (isset($_POST["Button"])) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST["Available_positions"])) {
        $Available_positions = $_POST["Available_positions"];
        if (strpos($Available_positions, '.') === false) {
            $pos = $Available_positions;
            $pos1 = 0;
        } else {
            $pieces = explode(".", $Available_positions);
            $pos = $pieces[0];
            $pos1 = $pieces[1];
        }

        $Payment_per_task = $_POST["Payment_per_task"];

        $hid = $_REQUEST['hid'];
        if ($pos1 > 0) {
            ?>
            <script>
                alert('Job Posting Suspended');
                window.location.href="edit_job.php?Id=<?= base64_decode($hid) ?>";
            </script>
            <?
        } else {
            dbQuery("update `jobs` set `wd2`='" . $Available_positions . "',`price`='" . $Payment_per_task . "' where `id`='" . $hid . "' and `email`='" . $_SESSION["userlogin"] . "'");
            ?>
            <script>
                window.location.href="employer.php";
            </script>
            <?
        }
    }
    $_SESSION['hid'] = $hid;
    if ($hid > 0) {
        $_SESSION["success"] = '';
    } else {
        $_SESSION["error"] = '';
    }
} else if (isset($_POST["Cancel"])) {
    $hid = $_REQUEST['hid'];
    dbQuery("update `jobs` set `status`='3' where `id`='" . $hid . "' and `email`='" . $_SESSION["userlogin"] . "'");
    $resJ = dbFetchArray(dbQuery("select * from `jobs` where `id`='" . $hid . "' and `email`='" . $_SESSION["userlogin"] . "'"), MYSQL_BOTH);

    if ($resJ["wd1"] != $resJ["wd2"]) {
        $CJ = $resJ["wd2"] - $resJ["wd1"];
        $CJFees = $CJ * $resJ["price"];
        dbQuery("insert into `myaccount`(`email`,`amount`,`type`,`createdate`,`jobid`) values('" . $_SESSION['userlogin'] . "','$CJFees','10',NOW(),'" . $resJ["id"] . "')");
        $rescurbal = dbFetchArray(dbQuery("select * from `user_registration` where `email`='" . $_SESSION['userlogin'] . "'"), MYSQL_BOTH);
        dbQuery("update `user_registration` set `current_balance`='" . ($rescurbal["current_balance"] + $CJFees) . "' where `email`='" . $_SESSION['userlogin'] . "'");
    }
    ?>
    <script>
        window.location.href="employer.php";
    </script>
    <?
}
?>
```

Comment: Line? What did you try? Error message?

Comment: base64_decode missing semi colon

Comment: Perhaps error in header.php

Comment: @AliMohammadi `It is displaying syntax error unexpected end of file` that's in the question

Comment: Try Include_once instas of include.

Comment: please comment the second line (include) and see if the error changes. maybe the error is in the included file

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Cut the large blocks of code one by one and refresh page. You can use [die](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) function to stop further script execution if needed to check whether the scripts gets executed to a certain point without generating errors.

When the error disappears, that means that it is in the block you have just cut. Then repeat procedure line by line, so you will be able to locate the mistake. It ahould be syntax error with brackets, quotes, semicolons or something like this.

Comment: `When I delete this code form the file the page is displaying correctly but again when I paste this code it is displaying the same error.` he is already using this technique

Comment: @Ejay no he is not using this technique, he is cutting ENTIRE text then he tries. -- zavg says to take it out piece by piece which is a good advice and should not be downvoted.

Comment: @Ejay You did not carefully read my answer

Comment: I did :) but i think this is not _THE_ answer to the problem. A suggestion, may be :) The problem _could be_ in his `include/header.php` file.

Comment: @Ejay I always thought the the community should not search syntax mistakes in someone's code, but should share the more valuable experience of how to deal with issues in common case.

Comment: @Ejay Ok, if problem is in header file, peace-by-peace cutting will easily show it.

Comment: @zavg you're right and we really appreciate others sharing their experiences :) but there must be a reason of having separate "answers" and "comments" section. 
And I apologize if you _really_ want me to take the downvote off the answer. I don't want to keep you hung into this discussion but SO won't let me take if off :(

Comment: @Ejay I don't care so much about down- and up-voting and I have got your point about answers and comments separation.

Answer (score 0):

Also, be sure your file encoding is UTF-8 without BOM.

```
include ("include/header.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION["userlogin"]))
{
    header("location: login.php");
    exit();
}
$edit = dbFetchArray(dbQuery("select * from `user_registration` where `email`='".$_SESSION["userlogin"]."'"),MYSQL_BOTH);
$Id = base64_decode($_REQUEST['Id']);
$up = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from `jobs` where `id`='".$Id."'"));
$status = stripslashes($up["highlighted"]);
$name = stripslashes($up["title"]);
$explode = explode(" ",$name);
$tit = isset($explode[0]) ? $explode[0] : '';
$col = isset($explode[1]) ? $explode[1] : '';
$cat = isset($explode[2]) ? $explode[2] : '';

$user = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from `user_registration` where `email`='".$_SESSION["userlogin"]."'"));
$fullname = stripslashes($user['fullname']);
$customer_id = $user['id'];
$current_balence = $user['current_balance'];

if(isset($_POST["Button"]))
{
    if(isset($_REQUEST["Available_positions"]))
    {
        $Available_positions = $_POST["Available_positions"];
        if(strpos($Available_positions,'.') === false)
        {
            $pos = $Available_positions;
            $pos1 = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            $pieces = explode(".",$Available_positions);
            $pos = $pieces[0];
            $pos1 = $pieces[1];
        }

        $Payment_per_task = $_POST["Payment_per_task"];

        $hid = $_REQUEST['hid'];
        if($pos1 > 0)
        {

?>
<script>
alert('Job Posting Suspended');
window.location.href="edit_job.php?Id=<?= base64_decode($hid)?>";
</script>
<?

        }
        else
        {
            dbQuery("update `jobs` set `wd2`='".$Available_positions."',`price`='".$Payment_per_task."' where `id`='".$hid."' and `email`='".$_SESSION["userlogin"]."'");

?>
 <script>
window.location.href="employer.php";
</script>
<?

        }
    }
    $_SESSION['hid'] = $hid;
    if($hid > 0)
    {
        $_SESSION["success"] = '';
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION["error"] = '';
    }
}
else
{
    if(isset($_POST["Cancel"]))
    {
        $hid = $_REQUEST['hid'];
        dbQuery("update `jobs` set `status`='3' where `id`='".$hid."' and `email`='".$_SESSION["userlogin"]."'");
        $resJ = dbFetchArray(dbQuery("select * from `jobs` where `id`='".$hid."' and `email`='".$_SESSION["userlogin"]."'"),MYSQL_BOTH);

        if($resJ["wd1"] != $resJ["wd2"])
        {
            $CJ = $resJ["wd2"] - $resJ["wd1"];
            $CJFees = $CJ * $resJ["price"];
            dbQuery("insert into `myaccount`(`email`,`amount`,`type`,`createdate`,`jobid`) values('".$_SESSION['userlogin']."','$CJFees','10',NOW(),'".$resJ["id"]."')");
            $rescurbal = dbFetchArray(dbQuery("select * from `user_registration` where `email`='".$_SESSION['userlogin']."'"),MYSQL_BOTH);
            dbQuery("update `user_registration` set `current_balance`='".($rescurbal["current_balance"] + $CJFees)."' where `email`='".$_SESSION['userlogin']."'");
        }

?>
<script>
window.location.href="employer.php";
</script>
<?
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks friend it did not help me could you please elaborate...

Answer (score -2):

If you don't have short tags active, you have to use `<?php`, becasue `<?`. Otherwise PHP ignore the code within `<? ... ?>`. So there will be missing brackets, therefore a syntax error like the one you're getting.

Comment: base64_decode again missin semi colon

Comment: That's not entirely correct, it depends on php.ini config. It usually is enough.

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ the first one is ok, the second one doesn't require a semicolon.

Comment: How on earth can a php function call not require a semi colon like that?

Comment: @Think with the default configuration it's required, and looking at the error (unexpected end of file) I guess the problem is this.

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ What I can see on that code is `$Id=base64_decode($_REQUEST['Id']);` and `<?=base64_decode($hid)?>`. As I said, the first one is correct, the second one **doesn't** require a semicolon.

Comment: Btw I would recommend to *try* before downvote :P

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php you're a C programmer, arn't you :P

Comment: Great, Thanks for that link. By the way Uby your downvotes are not about semi colon, they are about the fact that this is not an answer. Short tags do not generate a syntax error :)

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ Not per se, but in this case yes, they do. If short tag are not active  PHP ignores the code within `<? ... ?>`. So there will be missing brackets, therefore a syntax error.
Again, just try it :)

I edited the answer, hoping it's more clear now.